# How to decode data received in hex format into human readable format

Tags: eclipse, hex, decode

My project is based on Greenhouse Monitoring using Wireless Sensor Nodes. I am receiving data packets of temperature,light and humidity through sensor nodes (using Jennic Evaluation Kit JN5148) and Wireshark is analyzing these data packets successfully. These packets are of IEEE.802.15.4 protocol. Data packets are encrypted and present in hex format. They need to be decoded in order to get the values of temperature,humidity and light in human readable format. Wireshark does not support this. This decoding can only be done by making changes in the default program code of the sensor nodes kits. The program is written on C, and is run on Eclipse. How to write a piece of code in that existing code, that can decrypt the data and make it in human readable format?

A screenshot of this data analyzed through Wireshark is also attached.

[image]